# Checking connectivity of two bodies through open space

Tags: c++, algorithm, box2d, sfml, path-finding

The title is a little vague, but I'll explain better here.

## The Setup

I'm trying to program a little water level simulator, much like the water levels in the game, LIMBO. When an opening is made, allowing water to flow between two bodies of water, the levels equalize. The setup I have now is two containers, with blue blocks inside representing water levels. My mouse removes chunks of terrain away, and so, when an opening is made between the bodies, they should adjust and their Y values should move to match.

## Image examples:

**Semi-filled tanks:**
[image: Tanks]

**Equalized tanks:**
[image: Equalized]

Now, I know some maths could be done to figure out how much to adjust the levels and the ratios between different sized tanks. That part I think is pretty straight forward. But I can't figure out a good method of determining if and when the two bodies of water are connected.

*Any algorithm, pseudo-code, or references would be much appreciated!*

If you need more clarification, please, don't hesitate to ask. I look forward to all feedback and will edit my post for specific clarification.

*Thanks!*

~ **natebot13**

**BTW:** I'm using C++, SFML, and Box2D (Box2D is for some other physics related things I need, not necessarily needed for this example).

Comment: When the image changes, i.e.; when they become connected, make not of it. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils not quite what I mean. I mean, the two tanks will sit there, and when I drag the mouse across the terrain, the black gets removed, and I want an algorithm that calculates whether the two tanks have been connected yet, and if they have, boom, begin the "flow of water" by raising and lowering the water levels. There also could be multiple tanks all over the place and I want to determine which two have been connected once terrain is removed. Hopefully that made sense... (It made sense in my head) :P

Comment: It's hard to offer any ideas without knowing how these regions are defined in your code. Since the question is tagged with Box2D I first assumed the regions were defined with chain shapes, which is often how destructible terrain is done. But other people seem to be assuming you're dealing with some type of grid, and the diagram doesn't give much hint either way.

Comment: @iforce2d Yeah, sorry for the non-clarity. (I need to get better at that) Now I'm interested in that chain destructible terrain... Anyway, I realize the problem with my examples, however, I think Vikram's answer should suit fine if I can get that to fit. If not, I'll post a follow up question with better examples and explanations. Thanks! (BTW, iforce, your reputation precedes you. Thanks for your Box2D tutorials! They're a big help!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the edge of the container1 is connected to container2 at any point of time if so then adjust the water level. I guess you are working on a image so you can use the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithm to check if any of the edge pixels of container1 is connected to any of edge pixels of container2 and also get their positions.

**Algorithm :-**

> 1. puts edges of container1 in one set which is connected to a dummy parent1.
> 2. puts edges of container2 in another set which is connected to another dummy parent2.
> 3. say after every one second add the new added pixels to sets using connected components
> 4. check at end of every union whether dummy parent1 and parent2 are connected.
> 5. You can use DFS to check the exacts points of connection by starting from one edge set1 and reaching the other. The last pixel and
>      the previous first  pixel in edge set1 are connection end points.

**Note:-**

There is a implementation of disjoint set in c++ boost lib which might be useful in implementation of connected components.

Comment: I'm not working with an image, but the connected components reference seems close to what I'm looking for. I have something somewhat like an image (with blocks in a grid) and so the method will probably work out. I'll read up on it and see if I can understand it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @natebot13 a grid of pixel data is similar to image so it will working as long as the neighbourhood of pixels in grid is similar to what it is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start from left to right for example:
the right side of the left tank position is known.
search the column to its right for a blue square.
once found, search its surrounding squares - up, down and to the right.
keep searching until you get to the known left side of the right tank.